# Use of Passé Simple?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, subjonctif

Je lis le *Mirador* d'Elizabeth Gille (Nemirovsky).  Au Chap 8 je trouve:-

> Deux choses m'agaçaient particulièrement.  D'abord, que ma mère **persistât** a me traiter en fillette, ...

J'avais cru qu'il faudrait utiliser le passé imparfait dans un tel cas.  Je suis sûr que ce n'est pas un erreur du part de cette auteur.  Qu'est ce qui ce passe, s'il vous plait?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ce n'est pas le passé simple, c'est le [subjonctif imparfait](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/conjugaison/imparfait-du-subjonctif-54.php) du verbe ***persister***, demandé par la structure contenant le verbe ***agacer***.

C'est peut-être plus facile d'identifier cette structure au présent:

> Je pourrais croire à de la jalousie alors qu'en réalité ***ce qui m'agace, c'est qu'elle puisse*** se sentir en sécurité avec lui alors qu'il n'est même pas avec elle. ([Deep & Dark](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EsotEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT264&lpg=PT264&dq=%22ce%20qui%20m%27agace%20c%27est%20qu%27elle%22&source=bl&ots=Y_-naXRnDA&sig=ACfU3U0NuBtsYg5mwZp9eZvZtC3zzfl_bg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSwOO2vs_xAhXUh1wKHXmuDm0Q6AEwCHoECA8QAw#v=onepage&q=%22ce%20qui%20m%27agace%20c%27est%20qu%27elle%22&f=false): Nouvelle édition de Sophie S. Pierucci)

Le subjonctif est utilisé

> après la construction « cela + verbe » : cela m’arrange que, cela
> m’amuse que, cela me plaît que, cela m’inquiète que…
>
> - Cela m’agace que vous ***soyez*** systématiquement en retard. ([conjuguaison.com](https://www.conjugaison.com/grammaire/subjonctif.html))

Comment: Simplement mentionner le passé simple : _il/elle persista_.